# DataFactory convert string (year as 2 digits) to date

Tags: azure, datetime, azure-data-factory

I'm currently using a set of CSV log files in Azure Data Factory which I need to process and enter into an SQL table.

The problem is that some columns contain timestamp in which the year is represented by 2 digits (as opposed to the full 4 digit year).
ex. `01/03/17  22:10:33` has the date format of `MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss`

How do I convert this to a date or add '20' to the year in value? (ex. `01/03/17  22:10:33` would turn into `01/03/2017 22:10:33`). This would be quite simple to do in code, but I'm not sure how to do it within a Data Flow in Azure's Data Factory.

Edit: As @HimanshuSinha-msft mentioned, the apostrophes must be removed before parsing in order to work. I added an extra step to the Data Flow with the following: `toTimestamp(substring({Column Name},2,length({Column Name})-1), 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss')` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

ADF Data Flows fully support the Java standard date/time formatters. In your case, you would convert toTimestamp() as-is to get the date/time components lined-up, then convert to the output string you are looking to achieve with toString() as such:

toString(toTimestamp('01/03/17  22:10:33', 'MM/dd/yy  HH:mm:ss'), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')

More details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#totimestamp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#convert-to-dates-or-timestamps

Comment: I've tried to use the  `toTimestamp` function but the results are still the same, the values of the column still appear as `Null`.
I added a step on the Data Flow to add new column and entered the following expression `toTimestamp({Start Date}, "MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: In your example above, your Start Date has 2 spaces. Did you account for that in your formatter?

Comment: Yes I did. The values on the csv also are surrounded by apostrophes, like such `'01/03/17  22:10:33'` and I even tried to set the format as `'MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss'` (between quotation marks). I cannot figure what's going on. I've currently tried with 1 and 2 spaces, as well as with and without apostrophes - none worked

Comment: can you paste an example row from your CSV file?

Comment: I removed some of the unnecessary columns, but it still wasn't enough to be able to post here as a comment. https://gist.github.com/ItzEdgar/e54088fea8e4071e05195a942422f743

Comment: Looking at the data i see that the dates are in single quotes and thats the reason what @MarkKromerMSFT suggested in not working , i did a small test and if we can remove the single quotes it will work fine . I tried the below expression and its does work , please do let us know how its goes .

toTimestamp(substring(Somedate,2,length(Somedate)-1), 'MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss')

Answer (score 0):

This is a trick which was a blocker for me, but try this-

1. Go to sink
2. Mapping
3. Click on output format
4. Select the data format or time format you prefer to store the data into the sink.

Choose any of the defined formats you want.